# Could/Should we remind OP about the possibility of closing questions in the answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes I can see some answers at a question which is likely to be closed. Besides answers to the question, it may also remind the question might be closed later (eg:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11614333)) and sometimes with more detailed explaination on why it is off topic (eg:[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053393)).

My question is, is the reminder useful or just noise? I'm struggling if it should be edited out, because even it is not related to the question, it could be a friendly educational reminder to OP and future visitors that telling them which kinds of questions are on topic.

Comment: Users should not be using answer posts to discuss the content of the question, whether that's clarification on what the question means or telling the OP that their question is off topic. That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is the reminder useful or just noise

Noise!.

The posts you are referring to are almost 4(+) years old. I wouldn't worry too much about those. I assure you, they aren't too bad :). Ideally, we don't want to go cleansing old posts for *off-topic content*. What we can ensure is that new posts (more specifically *answers*) are **acceptable**.

So, if you see a *fairly new* post that answers a question and then adds **your question might be off-topic..but...**, check if the question is *on-topic on SO*, if **it is Not**,  then click that DV button on that answer . Also vote to close that question. If the *question* is **on-topic**, then simply edit out the **your question might be off-topic..but..** content from that answer (and optionally - try to leave a comment that explains why that question is not off topic).

Also note that, we expect people to know [what is on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)